# Why revalidateTag and revalidatePath doesn't work in jest test?

Tags: next.js, caching, jestjs

I'm developing an app in Nextjs. I have a server action that create a new product, and i'm trying to revalidate the cache after the creation, inside the server action.
It **works in development** but not in my tests, why ?

Here is the error in my jest test : `Invariant: static generation store missing in revalidateTag`

My server action :

```js
'use server';

export const createProduct = async (data: Product) => {
  const product = await prisma.product.create({ data });
  revalidateTag('product');
  return product;
};
```

My test that call the server action :

```js
describe('createProduct', () => {
  it('should return a product', async () => {
    const product = await createProduct({
      name: 'myProduct',
      // ...
    });

    expect(product).toHaveProperty('id');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In production or development, Next.js maintains a store that keeps track of pages that need to be revalidated. This error message suggests that the store which is supposed to keep track of which tags/pages to revalidate is not available in the test environment. Jest tests do not start up the full Next.js server environment, and therefore the store required to track revalidations is missing.

You can mock `revalidateTag` in your tests. This would bypass the actual ISR process and allow you to test that `revalidateTag` is called as expected without triggering the error. You may also want to do the same with `revalidatePath`.

```js
jest.mock('next/cache', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('next/cache'),
  revalidateTag: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
  revalidatePath: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
}));
    
describe('createProduct', () => {
  it('should return a product', async () => {
    const product = await createProduct({
      name: 'myProduct',
      // ...
    });
    
    expect(product).toHaveProperty('id');
    expect(revalidateTag).toHaveBeenCalledWith('product');
  });
});
```